# Odds Link Hover Behavouir

Tags: theming

Hello i dont seem to be able to change the colour of my links hover on my main content table. Ive tried everything but it seems to want to stay white. Can anyone identify the CSS i should be changing?

thanks

main left table here-
[enter link description here](http://onlinebanter.com/latest/all)

Comment: I've answered your question for you, but just as an FYI it may get closed as it's not directly Drupal related, and is better suited to [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
#main-content table tbody .views-field a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

It's a CSS specificity issue (also the reason that I never use ID's to style elements).  Check [this](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) page out from Stuff and Nonsense for a REALLY good explanation on CSS specificity (in relation to Star Wars).

Comment: ah thank you very much Chapabu. You are right it was a more general question sorry. Ive been troubling over this for weeks. I will check out your link too. Much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Actually Chapabu would it be rude of me to ask about my 'popular' boxes on the same page as mentioned above? My hover seems to work ok on IE and Firfefox but not on Chrome. This would be the last piece of the jigsaw for me. ive toiled with this for weeks too (years infact) thanks.